# Oil resistant marker for timing chain positioning

Tags: tools

This is a bit unusual of a question but does anyone know of really durable markers (as in Sharpie) that leave durable markings that resist erasure due to exposure to oil and other retarding agents?  I am trying to make marks on my VVT drums where and on my crankshaft where they need to align with markings on the timing chain (which are on the chain already).  There are sort of marks on the drums (but not on the crankshaft) already but it is confusing to distinguish them from some other markings that are also present but not relevant.  I tried using a Sharpie but it goes out over time and I haven't even zipped up the motor.  Is there something like oil based Sharpie that leaves almost like a thick trace of paint that doesn't erase easily, which mechanics would use?

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't want to use something like a small knife etc. to place a light scoring mark on the chain? Even a small surface scratch should be plenty to use as a mark without compromising the integrity of the chain.

Comment: Agree with @Shamtam. Using a scribe to scratch into the surface is a pretty decent idea.

Comment: I am marking a VVT drum. Not the chain. I think there are things called paint pens

Answer (score 1):

Paint pens are available at auto parts stores, they use them at salvage yards and the marks are nearly permanent (can be removed with alcohol). Personally I use Wite-Out from an office supply store. It's not as permanent as a paint pen, but lasts long enough to reassemble.